# How to include variable from one to another view in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel framework.I have a `CategoryController` and `allCategory.blade.php` view.I have a `welcome.blade.php` view.Now i want insert all categories value in the `welcome.blade.php` view.When i tried its show *Undefined variable: `$category`*

**allCategory.blade.php :**

```
@if(count($categories))
<table id="example2" class="table table-bordered table-hover" width="65%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th># Index</th>
            <th>Category Name</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <tr>
            <td>{{$category->sortInd}}</td>
            <td>{{$category->categoryName}}</td>
            <td><a class="btn btn-info badge bg-light-blue" href="{{route('editCategory',$category->id)}}">Edit</a> | <a class="btn btn-danger badge bg-red" href="{{route('deleteCategory',$category->id)}}">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
{{$categories->links()}}
@endif
```

**CategoryController:**

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::where('id', '>=', 1)->paginate(10);              
    return view('jobs.allCategory', ['categories' => $categories]);
}
```

I want this kind of **[solution](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/90/including-a-blade-template-within-another-template)**. But it doesn't work.

Now i want to show category value same as `allCategory.blade.php`.How can pass the variable value from one view to another view?

**N.B:** If you needed any file please let me know.

Comment: How did you load this view in your controller? Include snippet of your controller

Comment: @geckob Please see.I have updated my question.I can see perfect with `allCategory.blade.php` view but how can i see in `welcome.blade.php view` ?

Comment: How are you going to load `welcome` view in `allCategory` views? Is `welcome` will be your partial view?

Comment: Yes welcome is my partial view.

Comment: I want to load all data from `allCategery.blade.php` view to `welcome.blade.php` view.

Comment: show how you gonna load the `welcome` view?

Comment: I am going to load the category value same as doing in `allCategory.blade.php` and i can not see any value.

Comment: And i think it is not right approach to do load data of category view to welcome view.But i dont know how to do it.

Comment: What you are actually trying to do is not clear! You are saying `allCategory.blade.php is a partial view of master.blade.php and welcome.blade.php is a partial view of theme.blade.php`. There's no relation or connection between allCategory and welcome.blade.php.

Comment: I don't see any lines of loading welcome.blade.php

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim Ok let me clear.I have a admin panel theme and its template is `master.blade.php` and i have also a theme for general user which is `theme.blade.php`.`allCategory.blade.php` is the partial view of `master.blade.php` and `welcome.blade.php` is a partial view of `theme.blade.php`,.Yes there is no relation between them thats why i want to know how i get the value from `allCategory` view to `welcome` view.

Comment: You pass the array of the categories to the welcome.blade.php directly.

Comment: @MuhammadSumonMollaSelim cool!! .I get my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have got a solution with `compact()` function. In my `WelcomeController` I just query all data of category and use `compact()` function. `compact()` *function create an array from variables and their values*. So I can query different table data and use `compact()` so that I can view all data in `welcome` blade with `foreach()` loop. Something like below:

**WelcomeController :**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Category;
use App\Job;
use App\Http\Requests;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $jobs = Job::all();
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view("welcome",compact('categories','jobs'));
    }
```

Retrieve the value in **welcome.blade.php :**

```
 @foreach($categories as $category)
    <ul class="trends">
       <li><a href="#">{{ $category->categoryName}} &nbsp;<span class="item-numbers">(2,342)</span></a></li>
    </ul>
 @endforeach
```

Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 0):

Include your secondary view from your first view as in:

```
@include('welcome', ['categories' => $categories])
```

Access the value of the variable in `welcome.blade.php` with `$categories`, if this doesn't work, you're doing something else wrong, since it's the right way of doing it

Comment: `allCategory.blade.php` is a partial view of `master.blade.php` and `welcome.blade.php` is a partial view of `theme.blade.php`.I have tried your way before i posting the question but i got undefined variable $categories.

Comment: Is any problem if i use to main layouts? for me i have two.(master.blade.php and theme.blade.php)

Comment: I've tested this on a more complex scenario, main view extending another view, imports subview, subview imports another subview, still the values are passed. Your problem is elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

`$categories` must live in a `view composer`.

For example, add this to your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
view()->composer('welcome.blade.php', function($view)
{
    $categories = Category::all();
    $view->with('categories', $categories);
});
```

Now `$categories` will be available for all views and partial views.

You can of course extract the view composers to a dedicated service provider.

Comment: If i add this its throwing me an error. *syntax error, unexpected 'view' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION)*

Comment: Please try `View::composer` instead of `view()->composer`.

Answer (score -1):

You should be fine if you pass the data to the views correctly. One of the most basic way is something like this:

```
$category = []; // Some array

return View::make('welcome')->with('category', $category);
```

Comment: Please see.I have updated my question.I can see perfectly with `allCategory.blade.php` view but how can i see in `welcome.blade.php` view same data of categories?